# object loader three.js animation

Tags: animation, three.js

I am trying to implement Three.js animation using OBject Loader I am able to get the Object but Unable to set position and add animation.

Here is the demo of what I have done: http://yellowslice.tech/projs/three/

Please zoom in zoom out for testing the Object.

This is what I am expecting: https://clara.io/view/99c4d77b-4527-4f56-b856-75ce531137ff

Help Appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've not added an [AnimationMixer](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/animation/AnimationMixer) or any clips. Refer to [this example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_animation_scene.html#L115-L117) for how to create a mixer and play your animation.

```
var animationClip = object.animations[ 0 ];
mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer( object );
mixer.clipAction( animationClip ).play();
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response

I Tried implementing the AnimationMixer as per the demo.
But still unable to get the animation.
can there be anything wrong with the JSON